# How can I customize InventoryID selector?

Tags: acumatica

I need to add the attribute fields in the inventoryID selector as columns.

[attributes screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQX8O.png)

[sales orders - Inventory selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kaHJ.png)

I can add other columns but not the one of attributes...

[customization of selector columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPoLm.png)

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add attributes to stock items, these attributes are automatically attached to the object in some places but it does not show up in other places.
E.g. it can be automatically used as a column in Generic Inquiry or in the Report. 
It is automatically added as a column available for selection in some selectors, e.g. on the stock items screen itself[image: Stock Items selector with attributes]

However, on some other screens the functionality is disabled by default because of performance optimization. So, that's why you do not see it in Inventory selector in Sales Order screen.

To enable that on Sales Orders screen, you'll need a bit of coding.

1. Add the Attributes view to the graph

> ```
> public class SOOrderEntry_Extension_Example : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
> {
>   public CRAttributeList<InventoryItem> Answers;
> }
> ```

2. Publish the customization
3. You see Attributes in available columns list and you can add them to the selector columns
   [image]

> Note that the feature affects the performance of the screen.

Comment: Great! Thanks Dmitry! I can see the attributes in inventory selector in Stock Item screen but I have added the attributes view to the graph, then I published it and I can´t see the changes in inventory selector in Sales Order screen. What could be happening?

Comment: What version do you use? In older versions you would need to add the columns via customization after you've added the Attributes view

Comment: Hi Dmitry, forget what I told you, I had problems with the graph, I just solved it! Thanks for the information, it was very useful!

Answer (score -1):

This will actually be a bit more difficult to pull off.  The Attribute values for your entry are in another table, CSAnswers.  You would have to create a join with this table with your InventoryItem's NoteID and the AttributeID you wanted to display in your selector.